# Iterate over a list in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am working on Neo4j database and I want to replicate the scenario mentioned below,

I have 2 nodes Product and customer. In the customer node I am storing customer id and list of products. and in the product I am storing only productid.

Customer has values {custId:1,products:[1,2,3,4]} 
Product has values {productid:1},{productid:2},{productid:3},{productid:4}

Now what I want to do is,
I need to replace all these ids to an autogenerated ids after adding the nodes in the graph database. SOmething like set custId=ID(customer) and productId=ID(product) but what I am stuck at is how to iterate the list of products in customer node and change the product id to auto generated ids.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I do not understand your question.  Neo4j assigns each node its unique ID, which is autogenerated or you can use apoc.create.uuids(x) and it autogenerates new IDs

Comment: It assigns a unique ID but I am doing a load csv to import the data where I define relations and nodes but as soon as the data is imported I want to update all user defined ids to autogenerated ids

Answer (score 2):

The idea of storing the product IDs are automatically generated by database in an array of user property - it is the wrong idea. In all senses.

The graph spirit - is to establish a relationship between the node `Customer` and its corresponding nodes `Product`, and then delete the property `products` from `Customer` and `productid` from `Product`:

```
MATCH (Customer:Customer)
  UNWIND Customer.products as prodID
    MATCH (Product:Product {productid: prodID})
    MERGE (Customer)-[r:hasProduct]->(Product)
WITH Customer, count(Product) as mergedProduct
     REMOVE Customer.products
WITH count(Customer) as totalMerged
MATCH (Product:Product)
    REMOVE Product.productid
```

Comment: I want to store it in array of user property because I am using LOAD CSV to load the data then I want to update the ids so I want this to be used